# Using multiple OR LIKE statements

Tags: sql, filter

I have a database and I want to filter for some entries. This is how the filter looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM Item WHERE 1=1  AND Favorite = 1 AND (  DocType = ?  OR  DocType = ?  OR  DocType = ?  OR  DocType = ? )  AND (Title Like ? OR Location LIKE ? OR DocType LIKE ? OR ProType LIKE ?)
```

The filter almost works. I want to focus on the last part:

```
AND (Title Like ? OR Location LIKE ? OR DocType LIKE ? OR ProType LIKE ?)
```

Because it seems like

```
 OR DocType LIKE ? OR ProType LIKE ?
```

is ignored. When switching Location with DocType for example:

```
AND (Title Like ? OR DocType LIKE ? OR Location LIKE ? OR ProType LIKE ?)
```

I can find anything related to DocType. Location can't be found anymore (just as ProType). So I guess I wrote it down wrong.

How would I need to write it down so I can filter for Title, Location, DocType and ProType?

Comment: Please add sample input and output data to make your question more concrete.

Comment: For Example: In a searchbar I enter "Test". "Test" is a Value of "DocType". The output is empty but it should be the files with the "DocType" Values of "Test". But when I enter "TestLocation" which is a Value of "Location" I can see the files with the "Location" Value "TestLocation". Now when switching "Location" with "DocType" I can search and find "Test" but I cannot find "TestLocation" anymore.

Comment: Should "AND (Title Like ? OR Location LIKE ? OR DocType LIKE ? OR ProType LIKE ?)" actually work?

Comment: Do you proivde any LIKE wildcards?

Comment: This is just strange `AND (  DocType = ?  OR  DocType = ?  OR  DocType = ?  OR  DocType = ? )` is this a typo in the question or is this repetitive check against the same column part of the actual query?

Comment: When you type "ABC" in the search bar will `?` in the query be "ABC" or "%ABC%" or different for different `?`?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson it will be "%ABC%"

Answer (score 0):

You have two checks against the `DocType` column, one with = and one with LIKE and since you have added % to your search string the = will most likely return false so nothing will be returned since the two checks are grouped with an AND so your WHERE condition will become (shortened)

```
WHERE DocType = '%ABC%' AND DocType LIKE '%ABC'
```

I think you should simply remove the part directly before the AND in your query

```
WHERE 1=1 AND Favorite = 1 AND (Title Like ? OR Location LIKE ? OR DocType LIKE ? OR ProType LIKE ?)
```